# bashdb error after adding user to group listed via ls -l $(tty)

Tags: centos, trepan

I see that this question has been posted and answered.  However, the post answer does not work for me.  The posted answer has 2 solutions:

## 1  -  run bashdb as root

```
this does not work for me because the script I am trying to debug must be run as mqm.  This script exits when it sees that it is being run (via bashdb) as root.
```

## 2  -  Add the user to the group listed by ls -l $(tty)

```
I ran this command and got:
```

mqm@localhost.localdomain(/var/mqm/scripts): ls -l $(tty)
crw--w----. 1 root tty 136, 0 Jun 17 10:11 /dev/pts/0

```
 I ran (as root)  usermod -a -G root mqm
```

and verified that the root group contains mqm  -
then logged in as mqm, I re-ran
bashdb myscript
and again received this error
/usr/share/bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/0: Permission denied

Comment: Sorry for the post title.  Stackoverflow complained about my initial title attempt because there was already a post with that title.  This post is about bashdb error =  /usr/share/bashdb/lib/setshow.sh: line 91: /dev/pts/0: Permission denied.  It is not viable for me to try bashdb logged in as root and after adding mqm to the group (see above) I still get the permission error.

Answer (score 0):

Bashdb also has a `--tty` option.

By default, `bashdb ...` is the same as `bashdb --tty $(tty)`.  So try giving an explicit `--tty` argument with a name of a tty or psuedo tty that you know you can write to.

Here is how you might test having access to the tty before running bash. Suppose the tty is `/dev/pts/2` then run

echo hi > /dev/pts/2

If that works, then try `bashdb -tty /dev/pts/2 ...`